# Group by on pandas datetime with null values

Tags: pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, grouping

So im looking at manipulating data to perform autoregression forecasting on the data. I have managed to group by the week without any issues, however the weeks that do not have any flagged values is left out of the created dataframe. The shape of the data frame is (28, 141), meaning only 28 weeks are grouped, the missing weeks of the year need to show null so the shape is (52, 141)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **right** **join** to set of dates you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1-feb-2020", freq="4d", periods=28)})

(df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period("w")).count()
 .join(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("1-jan-2020", "31-dec-2020", freq="3d").to_period("w").unique())
      ,how="right")
)
```